# Phalcon Installation error on Windows server 2008 R2, PHP 5.5.24

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008-r2, phalcon

my client's server is windows Server 2008 R2 with which they have installed PHP on IIS PHP version 5.5.24

I have tried to install Phalcon dll Extension x86, also added the "extension=php_phalcon.dll" to the php.ini file as per instructed on the website, restarted the server/apache but the extension is not loaded

if anybody can help would be much appreciated...

here is the link to screenshot of the phpinfo https://app.box.com/s/08tcb2a913jyts1wjx03no0yeuvync5f

Comment: What ISS version? Did you take the Phalcon dll with or without the `NTS` ?

Comment: Did you restart the web server modules? Did you check logs for errors? You need to use following Phalcon .dll: `Phalcon 3.0.1 - Windows x86 for PHP 5.5.0 NTS (vc11) `

Comment: @Timothy IIS version 7, i have tried both NTS and without NTS Phalcon dll

Comment: @Luke - Yes i did restart the server modules after each time i try with the new Phalcon dll (with NTS & Without NTS) all with VC11, But in the PHP Settings window in IIS it shows the Phalcon dll as active, but in the phpinfo file it doesn't shows anything about Phalcon.

Comment: Are you sure you are updating the correct php.ini file?

Comment: @Timothy - yes i checked that, it's the correct php.ini file which is shown in the phpinfo under "Loaded Configuration File", pls check my attached image file.

Comment: A very dirty and non recommended workaround is to install vagrant and host your website on some lightweight linux. I dont't have any more ideas what could be wrong with your configuration. Edit: please check phpinfo running from your terminal php. Maybe it is working there and that's why your gui shows phalcon as loaded